# Why is the JSON content missing from my XMLHttpRequest sent to the ESP32 Arduino webserver?

Tags: json, arduino, xmlhttprequest, webserver, esp32

I have an ESP32 running a webserver with a UI that needs to send an object array to the ESP in a JSON. The JSON string on the user end is correct, the request is received by the esp but does not contain any JSON content.
This is on the user end:

```
var dataWhite = [{hour: 10, minute:5, light:2000},{hour: 11, minute:10, light:2050}];
function uploadWhiteData() {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("POST", "/uploadWhiteData", true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
              }
            };
            xhr.send(JSON.stringify(dataWhite));
          }
```

On the server end I tried getting to the JSON like this:

```
server.on("/uploadWhiteData", HTTP_POST, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
    if (request->hasParam("plain", true)) {
      String data = request->getParam("plain", true)->value();
      Serial.print("Incoming JSON: ");
      Serial.println(data);
    }
    request->send(200);
  });
```

(in this case the hasParam() always returns as false)
and like this:

```
server.on("/uploadWhiteData", HTTP_POST, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
  request->onRequestBody([](const String& body, size_t length) {
    if (request->header("Content-Type") == "application/json") {
      String data = body;
      Serial.print("Incoming JSON: ");
      Serial.println(data);

    }
  });

  request->send(200);
});
```

(with this it prints "incoming json" and then nothing)
I also tried with a get request, that resulted in the same outcome.

Comment: does ESPAsyncWebServer support "plain"? it is not some general way of getting the body of the request

Comment: https://github.com/me-no-dev/ESPAsyncWebServer#json-body-handling-with-arduinojson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [setting up the server](https://github.com/me-no-dev/ESPAsyncWebServer#setting-up-the-server)  on how to create a HTTP_POST route. You can also take a look at my example [here](https://www.e-tinkers.com/2019/11/build-an-esp32-web-server-and-ir-remote/) (scroll down to the section "ESP32 Web Sever Back-end Codes" where the main.cpp is shown). Basically the api should be:

```cpp
server.on("/your_route", HTTP_POST, onRequest, onFileUpload, onBody);
```

With the async nature of the web server, when the request is received the message body is not available yet, the API handling this with 3 callback functions, each is called at the different stages of the request, the way you are doing, you are expecting the request body to be available when handling the `onRequest` callback, it actually only available when the `onBody` callback is triggered.

```cpp
void onRequest(AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
    // dummy callback function for handling params, etc.
}

void onFileUpload(AsyncWebServerRequest *request, const String& filename, size_t index, uint8_t *data, size_t len, bool final) {
    // dummy callback function signature, not in used in this example
}

void onBody(AsyncWebServerRequest *request, uint8_t *data, size_t len, size_t index, size_t total) {
  
    Serial.printf("body=%s\n", (char*) data);
    // deserialise the json data, do what you want with the data
    request->send(200, "text/plain", "Ok");
}

void setup() {
  // your setup code here 

  server.on("/uploadWhiteData", HTTP_POST, onRequest, onFileUpload, onBody);

  server.begin();
}

void loop() {

}
```